# how to create a while in jquery for alwayes in browser

Tags: jquery, chat

I would like to create a chat script, and check for check new replies.

I need to a while Once  every 4 seconds checking new message in file db.php

Sample :

```
function while_check_seen()
{
    $(".replay").delay(4000).load("../db_pms.php?action=check");    
    while_check_seen()
}
```

This `while` worked, but used a lot of CPU!

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: tanX ric , with Ajax is every 4 second checking a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".replay").load("../db_pms.php?action=check");    
}, 4000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery plug-in that will periodically poll a given URL and (optionally) update a page as necessary.

Such as here: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/periodic-updater

Comment: tanX tomas , i want other ways

Comment: very tanX tomas , https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater this id very good , but i need other way !